# Python running on Ubuntu - TypeError: Object of type 'Point' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, digital-ocean

I have spent quite a bit of time stying to resolve this issue, i have googled and gone through posts with no success. I have a python script which works just fine on my macOsx computer, but i needed to run the script online so i am using digitalOcean for that.

I have an HTTP request, where i post data using postman to a Flask Application

```
@app.route('/addtransaction', methods = ['POST'])
def add_transaction():
    data = request.get_json()
    private = account.get_private_key()
    public = account.get_public_key()


    transaction = account.create_transaction(data)
    string_transaction = str(transaction)
    signature = ecdsa.sign(string_transaction, private, curve=curve.secp256k1, 
                  hashfunc=ecdsa.sha256)

    index = blockchain.add_transaction(public, transaction, signature, 
              string_transaction) 

    #Broadcast the transaction to the Peer Network 
    #First create the transaction object 
    trans_object = {'sender_id': public, 
                'transaction': transaction,
                'signature': signature, 
                'string_transaction': string_transaction }

     #Then broadcast using the Transaction Publisher we created above
     peerServer.broadcast_transaction(trans_object, transaction_pu)

     is_valid = ecdsa.verify(signature, string_transaction, public, 
            curve.secp256k1, ecdsa.sha256)

     transaction_id = transaction['transaction_id']
     response = {'message': f'Transaction id: {transaction_id} will be 
     added to block {index}',
            'transaction_details': string_transaction, 'signature_valid': 
            is_valid }
     return jsonify(response), 201
```

I get the error during the Broadcast Transaction method when i try to run the jsondumps - Method below

```
def broadcast_transaction(self, transaction, publisher):
    j_transaction = json.dumps(transaction, sort_keys=True)
    publisher.send_json(j_transaction)
    print(f'Just broadcasted transaction: {j_transaction}')
    return
```

I get the error TypeError: Object of type 'Point' is not JSON serializable

Full report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matshidiso/blockchainProjects/blockchain/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/matshidiso/blockchainProjects/blockchain/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/matshidiso/blockchainProjects/blockchain/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/matshidiso/blockchainProjects/blockchain/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/matshidiso/blockchainProjects/blockchain/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/matshidiso/blockchainProjects/blockchain/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "pythonBlockchain.py", line 330, in add_transaction
    peerServer.broadcast_transaction(trans_object, transaction_pu)
  File "pythonBlockchain.py", line 211, in broadcast_transaction
    j_transaction = json.dumps(transaction, sort_keys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'Point' is not JSON serializable
```

I am confused because this same script runs just fine on my personal macbook without errors, which leads me to think that perhaps the problem is with the operating system. What am i missing here?

Is there differences running a python script on a macbook and ubuntu server?

Comment: can you do pip freeze on both environments? I suspect they might have different package versions installed

Comment: The packages are all the same version, the Python version on Ubuntu is Python 3.6.6 and on my personal computer its 3.6.5 and

Comment: What does the `transaction` object look like on your Mac? On the Ubuntu server? Have you verified that all class attributes are JSON serializable? Looks like there is an embedded Point class in there that is the issue.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was one of the outputs to the transaction objects - the public key. Its output was a point on a curve instead of a tuple, like i have in my personal computer.

Comment: I had used a specific version of fastecdsa and made some changes to the file on my personal computer and forgot about it. So the points on the curve were not serializable . . . . that was the problem, i just had to change the public key output.